# Cython化による多次元配列の内積計算の高速化

Tags: python3, cython

多次元配列の内積を計算するプログラムの高速化を検討しております。

Pythonで作成したソースをもとにCythonでも実装しました。
私の環境では両者の速度は以下の通りです。

Python : 0.17599 [sec]
Cython : 0.17589 [sec]

Cythonにより速くなることを期待しておりましたが殆ど変わりませんでした。

Cythonについては初心者です。コードにおかしなところ等ありますでしょうか？
PythonおよびCythonのソースコードを以下に示します。
なお、恐縮ですが、少なくとも10倍以上の処理速度向上を望んでおります。

## Python

`$ python cal_area_from_dem.py`

### cal_area_from_dem.py

```py
import numpy as np
import time as t

start = t.time()
np.random.seed(0)
xyz = np.random.rand(4, 100000, 3)
vec = np.random.rand(3, 100000)

def main():

    x = np.array(xyz[:, :, 0])
    y = np.array(xyz[:, :, 1])
    z = np.array(xyz[:, :, 2])

    cvec = vec[:, :]

    p0 = np.array([x.T, y.T, z.T])
    p0 = [p0[:, i, :] for i in range(100000)]
    p_ref = np.array([x[0], y[0], z[0]])
    d_vec = p0 - np.repeat(p_ref, 4).reshape(100000, 3, 4)

    dat0 = np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", cvec.T, d_vec)

    print('Python : ' + str(round((t.time() - start),5)) + ' [sec]')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Cython

`$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace; python main_cal_area_from_dem.py`

### main_cal_area_from_dem.py

```py
import cal_area_from_dem as c
import numpy as np
import time as t

def main():
    start = t.time()
    np.random.seed(0)
    xyz = np.random.rand(4, 100000, 3)
    vec = np.random.rand(3, 100000)
    test = c.cal_area_from_dem(xyz, vec)
    print('Cython : ' + str(round((t.time() - start),5)) + ' [sec]')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### cal_area_from_dem.pyx

```py
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t np_float_t
ctypedef np.int32_t np_int_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cpdef np.ndarray[np_int_t, ndim=1] cal_area_from_dem(
    np.ndarray[np_float_t, ndim=3] xyz,
    np.ndarray[np_float_t, ndim=2] vec):

    cdef np.ndarray[np_float_t, ndim=2] x, y, z, cvec, p_ref, new_dat0
    cdef np.ndarray[np_float_t, ndim=3] p0, d_vec

    x = np.array(xyz[:, :, 0])
    y = np.array(xyz[:, :, 1])
    z = np.array(xyz[:, :, 2])

    cvec = vec[:, :]

    p0 = np.array([x.T, y.T, z.T])
    p0 = np.array([p0[:, i, :] for i in range(100000)])
    p_ref = np.array([x[0], y[0], z[0]])
    d_vec = p0 - np.repeat(p_ref, 4).reshape(100000, 3, 4)

    new_dat0 = np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", cvec.T, d_vec)
```

### setup.py

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("cal_area_from_dem", ["cal_area_from_dem.pyx"])]
)
```

Comment: 複数回（とりあえず10回程度）実行した場合の平均はどうなりますか？

Comment: 10回の平均は次の通りです。
Python : 0.172122 [sec]、
Cython : 0.170205 [sec]

Comment: 一応正常にCythonが動いていて、なおかつそれほど早くなっていないようですね（自分の環境でも同程度の僅かな速度改善がありました）。さて、既にご存知でしたら恐縮ですが、Cython公式でNumpyと組み合わせて高速化する方法についてのリファレンスが公開されているので、参考にされてみてはいかがでしょうか。[Working with NumPy — Cython 3.0a0 documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記サイトはみていなかったので確認してみます。

Comment: numpyどおしの比較になっている気がするのですが。よって、Pythonでも、Cythonでも、同じではないでしょうか？なぜ、違うことを期待されているのでしょうか？。（あまり、深く理解していないので、間違ったコメントならば、無視して下さい。）

Comment: np.show_config()などで、実体として、どのようなライブラリが動作しているかも、確認されたほうがいい気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。以前、numpyを使わないようにソースを修正してCython化したら爆速（8000倍程度）した経験があるので、そうかもしれません。また、np.show_config()というのがあるのですね。試してみます。なお、別途、多少精度が落ちてもいいので、ロジックを見直し中です。進展がありましたらご報告いたします。

Comment: `以前` がどのように高速化したのか分かりませんが、自分のコメントの通りNumpyもC/C++で実装されているため大きく変わることはないと思います。